# How to stop a 3½-year-old from putting fingers in his ears when he is not comfortable?

Tags: pre-schooler, extended-family, habits, ear

Whenever I take my 3.5-year-old nephew to some unknown place or somewhere he is not comfortable, he puts his fingers in his ears as if he wants to avoid a loud noise.

Even if I take him to some dark place he does the same thing. Initially I saw him putting his fingers in his ears while traveling by train, then he started doing the same thing in the car, bus, even in my home when he was watching a horror movie.

I want to know how to come over this situation.

Comment: Wait ... you let a 3½ year old boy watch horror movies??

Answer (score 5):

Is there a reason you want to overcome this? Is it a medical necessity? Is it harming him in anyway?

It seems that it is just a way for him to cope, which can be a good thing. Unless there is some harm to the child, I don't see why you would want to fix this.

Having said that, if it is really concerning you, offer him another way to cope. This could be hugging/holding him when he is exposed to such situations. Try distracting him, or maybe letting him carry his favorite toy around (which is typically comforting).